# Could not instantiate bean class

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am trying to interact hibernate with spring in my GWT project, below is my code

```
    public class MyWebServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
    MyWebService {

public void myfirstmethod() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public String signIn(String userid, String password)  {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    "applicationContext.xml");
    MySQLRdbHelper rdbHelper = (MySQLRdbHelper) ctx.getBean("ManagerJobs");
    **//THIS IS THE POINT WHERE IT THROWS THE EXCEPTION**

    return rdbHelper.getAuthentication(userid, password);
}
```

}

```
      public class MySQLRdbHelper {


private Session session;
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  /* FOR COUNT QUERY
   * session.createCriteria(RuleSet .class)   
   .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()   
           .add( Projections.rowCount() ) )   
   .add( Subqueries.geAll("entry_id", bolgsEntries) )   
   .list();   
 */
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

public String getAuthentication(String userid, String password)
{
    //Some detals like credit card are commented in the class
    User users = null;
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(User.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("userName", userid));
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("password", password));

    List rsList = crit.list();
    for(Iterator it=rsList.iterator();

    it.hasNext();
    )
    {
        users = (User)it.next();
        System.out.println(users.getUserName());
    }
    session.close();
    return users.getUserName();
}
```

}

```
         APPLICATIONCONTEXT.XML
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd"
     default-lazy-init="true">

       <!-- Datasource for database connection -->
       <bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/patients" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>

         <bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"> 
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
        <property name="annotatedClasses"> 
         <list>  
 <value>com.Patient.shared.User</value> 

       </list> 
       </property> 
        </bean>
       <bean id ="ManagerJobs" class= "patient.persistence.MySQLRdbHelper">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> 
     </bean>
```

THIS IS THE EXCEPTION

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ManagerJobs' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing slf4j in your classpath as indicated by

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

Get it and add to application.

Comment: thanks , i've added  slf4j-api-1.3.1.jar    and                    slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar ,    but the problem is still there   any suggestion    thanks

Comment: @junaidp add slf4j jars with the same versions. Does the same problem mean that you see the same `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory`?

Comment: @junaidp also where do you put your jars? I remember that in hosted mode I had to put slf4j jars in WEB-INF/lib. They didn't get picked up from regular classpath.

Comment: yes you are right , i just put them in lib folder and it solved the problem   thanks alot

Answer (score -2):

```
This is my Controller file..........
@Controller
public class AutoCompleteController {
    //@Resource(name = "blCatalogService")
    //protected CatalogService catalogService;
        @RequestMapping(value = "/AutoComplete", produces = "application/json")
        public@ResponseBodyList<Product>AutoComplete(HttpServletRequest request,
             HttpServletResponse response,Model model, CatalogService catalogService){
    List <Product> list=new ArrayList<Product>();
    String autostr=request.getParameter("autocomp");
    System.out.println("AutoComplete Controller" + autostr);
    try { 
        //database query searchString;
        CatalogService catalogService1=new CatalogServiceImpl();
        list =  catalogService1.findProductsByName(autostr);
        System.out.println("Result:"+list);

    } 
        catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error inside AutoComplete Controller");
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;

    }

    }
    This is my js File


function ajaxAutoComplete(a)
{

    var querystring = "&isAjax=1&autocomp="+jQuery("#autocomp").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: a,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",`enter code here`
        data: querystring,
        success: function (data){} 
    });
}
that the time it will produced that error.
500 Could not instantiate bean class
org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.service.CatalogService]:
```